# Returning a unique row if condition returns multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

I am writing an algorithm for a Vehicle Routing Problem. When the driving time from some seed city to some other city is minimal, it should be added to my route. To check this, I use

```
new_point_row_df = emte_df[emte_df["seed_time"] == emte_df.seed_time.min()]
```

Which gives me the entire row of the new city. Then I use

```
lat = new_point_row_df["Lat"].squeeze()
long = new_point_row_df["Long"].squeeze()
```

Which gives me the coordinates of that city. Then I pass these coordinates alongside my "home" coordinates (The coordinates of where the distribution centre lies), to a function, "time_to_home" 
which calculates, no surprises here, the time_to_home.

```
time_to_home((lat,long), veghel_coordinates)
```

In most cases this works perfectly fine. However, in the rare case that `emte_df.seed_time.min()`returns multiple rows (So 2 cities lie at *exactly* the same driving time from my seed point), lat & long are *pandas Series* instead of numpy floats. When I pass series to my time_to_home function, it breaks down and throws

`TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`which makes perfect sense.

My question is: If `emte_df.seed_time.min()`returns multiple rows, how can I make it so that I select only *one* to pass into my lat/long coordinates and subsequently time_to_home function? It doesn't matter which row is selected, as long it is only one so my time_to_home function doesn't break down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```py
ew_point_row_df = emte_df[emte_df["seed_time"] == emte_df.seed_time.min()].iloc[0]
```

This will just select the first row every time.